# Closed form for $\sum^{\infty}_{{i=n}}ix^{i-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

How can I find a closed form for:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{{i=n}}ix^{i-1}$$

It looks like that's something to do with the derivative

Comment: The series doesn't converge, since the summand doesn't depend on the summation index.

Comment: I think the series $$\sum^\infty_{i=n}i\cdot x^{i-1}$$

Comment: MathMan: Accepting answers is much appreciated. Correcting one's question is necessary as well. As it stands, the question is absurd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sum^\infty_{r=n}rx^{r-1}=\dfrac {d\left(\sum^\infty_{r=n}x^r\right)}{dx}$$

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), $\sum^\infty_{r=n}x^r=\dfrac{x^n}{1-x}$ if $|x|<1$

---

Alternatively,

let $S_n=\sum^m_{r=n}rx^{r-1}=n\cdot x^{n-1}+(n+1)x^n+(n+2)x^{n+1}+\cdots+(m-1)x^{m-2}+mx^{m-1}$

So, multiplying by $x,$   $x\cdot S_n=\sum^\infty_{r=n}rx^r=n x^n+(n+1)x^{n+1}+(n+2)x^{n+2}+\cdots+(m-1)x^{m-1}+mx^m$

On subtraction, $$(1-x)S_n=nx^{n-1}+(x^n+x^{n+1}+\cdots+x^{m-1})-mx^m$$
$$=nx^{n-1}+x^n\frac{(1-x^{m-n})}{1-x}-mx^m=nx^{n-1}+\frac{(x^n-x^m)}{1-x}-mx^m$$

Now, if $m\to\infty$ and $|x|<1,x^m\to0$

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322993/show-that-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-nxn-0-for-x-in0-1), $\lim_{m\to\infty}mx^m=0$ if $|x|<1$

Comment: @MathMan, please find my comment in the question

Answer (score 4):

Recall the power series:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

holds for all $|x|<1$.

Then take the derivates, you get:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\geq1}nx^{n-1}$$

Comment: The first identity is incorrect unless $|x|<1$

Comment: But then the derivative would be incorrect too for $|x|<1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Good point!

Comment: I've made the correction

Comment: @DannyCheuk, also here the series starts with $i=n$ not from $0$

Comment: Derp, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The series begins from $\,i=n\,$, @labbhattacharjee ? I'd say the first one begins at $\,i=0\,$ , and the second one from $\,i=1,$ . BTW, the running index in both series must be $\,i\,$, not $\,n\,$...or change the running index, of course.

Comment: @DannyCheuk, $\sum_{i=n}^\infty x^n=x_n\cdot \sum_{i=n}^\infty1$. How has it become $\frac1{1-x}?$

Comment: The first series's index **still** must begin at $\,n=0\,$ or else it does *not* represent the left side function...

Comment: @DonAntonio Alright got it!